# I want to set up a shopping cart rule Buy 3 for £40

Tags: checkout

I sell coffee so a lot of my products are configurable. I want customers to but 3 tins of coffee for £40 but it is not working.

In actions I have changed the apply to:
Fixed price for product set

the discount amount is: 40

and I have added the sku's for simple products.. and the category.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Same product coffee? OR 3 different. 3 same can be done on product level using tier pricing

Answer (score 0):

If it is three times the same product, use tier price rules.

If it is three different products this works with a **cart price rule**.

For this do following rule conditions:

1. Select product / category to be discounted
2. Select "Article amount total" >= 3
3. Select a caclulated, percentual discount
4. Apply.

The advantage is now, the person taking 4 items will be discounted the same and not "punished" on the fourth product. Otherwise, you could restict the rule to "total quantity for discounted articles" to 3 and your good to go.

Comment: Hi Thank you for your reply! Is it possible to do this with 3 different products? The problem is I have 5 products and I want customers to be able to choose any 3 of the 5 for 40 pounds. Can I do this?

Comment: I edited the answer.

Comment: along the lines of what @BernhardPrange is saying. You could also set use an attribute to filter the promotion against. Just make sure the attribute has "Use for Promo Rule Conditions" set to yes and it will appear as an option for your promotional price rule.